# DateTime storage issue:: Data overloads

Tags: vb.net

I have defined a field in my database table to store time.  The default length of the field is 8.  I am storing time from TimeODay which is displaying 12:44:10 PM
which overloads the data.  How can I store this data to my DateTime field?

Thanks

Comment: You should not use a string field to store a date - use a date type, then you don't have to worry about any of this.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
Dim CurrentTime As String
CurrentTime = TimeOfDay.ToLongTimeString.ToString.Replace(":", "")
CurrentTime = CurrentTime.Replace(" ", "")
If CurrentTime.Length = 7 Then
    CurrentTime = "0" & CurrentTime
End If
MsgBox(CurrentTime, MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly)
```

This will return the `TimeOfDay` as follows:

Input: 12:44:10 PM
Output: 124410PM

You could then use some code when displaying it to return it to default formatting.

EDIT 1:

Or even better, you could use 24hr time...This would display 12:44:10 PM as 12:44:10 (8 Chars) or 4:30:45 PM as 16:30:45.

Comment: If using the first option, I would also verify length and append a 0 to the front if needed.  So if 3:14:48 am, then comes out "031448AM".  It will help later when you have to pull this data back out to format.